# svn path to repository

Tags: svn

I have svn installed at /home/subversion on a linux server - there is a ROOT folder there containting folders such as db and conf. There are no folders that map to project names, please could someone tell how to list existing projects and what the path to the repository would be? i.e. home/subversion or home/subversion/ROOT

Thanks
Jon

Answer (score 4):

The path to your repository will be `/home/subversion/ROOT`. Apparently you named your repository ROOT. So:

```
svn ls file:///home/subversion/ROOT
```

should give you a (perhaps empty) listing of files in the top level of the repository.

The subdirectories such as `db` and `conf` in the repository directory itself are part of the repository format and are not accessed directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should let us know whether you are trying to use Apache or svnserve to access the repository. You need one of these tools installed to server up the repository files over http://, https:// or svn:// protocols.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350588/subversion-how-do-i-control-user-access-for-single-repository-when-svnparentpat) about the Apache Configuration. You should be able to server up single or multiple repositories with svnserve too.