# SVN user access to certain projects configuration

Tags: svn, unix, configuration, ubuntu-10.04

i'm completely new to the unix systems... been playing around about 2 weeks.
i've managed to install subversion and create a repositories.

lets say we have users:

```
internal_developer
external_developer_1
external_developer_2
```

we have a projects:

```
repositories/project1
repositories/project2
repositories/project3
```

how can i configure the access for each user and project independantly.

1. internal_developer - can access all projects ( rw )
2. external_developer_1 - can only access project1 ( rw )
3. external_developer_2 - can only access project2 ( rw )

when i say "can only access" it means that he can not see the repositories/* content, only the projects he is working with.

i've tried to look for some manuals or tutorials how can i do this... but all of them are for more expierienced users then i am...

---

any help is appreciated.

### ---

Edit. ( can not yet answer my question )

in the file `/etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf`

at the location of `AuthUserFile` stored only user names and passwords.

then

need to add new line: `AuthzSVNAccessFile /usr/passwd/svn.authz`

then there goes the syntax from Floyd ^^.

I looked here: [Subversion - how do I control user access for single repository when SVNParentPath is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350588/subversion-how-do-i-control-user-access-for-single-repository-when-svnparentpa)

And with the groups it looks more like it.

---

Stil, one missing part left... can not configure the admin user to see all repositories when comes to http://xxxxxx/svn/

gives an error

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /svn/ on this server.

even i puted in the svn.authz:

```
[/]
@internal = rw
```

Comment: Is this one repository with three projects, or three separate repositories? It makes a big difference in the configuration.

Comment: It is only one repository. With many projects in it.

Comment: hmm... now i started to doubt... What you call repository?

Before i added a AuthzSVNAccessFile, when i was accessing HTTP/svn i could see there all of the projects.

each of the project has they're own Revision history.

Comment: If each project has its own revision numbering, there are three separate Subversion repositories. Here's an easy question, in the ACTUAL location of these repositories, how many `hooks` directories are there? Each repository will have its own `hooks` directory. If these are three different repositories, I believe each will need its own authorization configuration (although they may be able to share the same auth file).

Comment: Now they are sharing the same authentication file... and i can specify there properties for each project who can access it.

Comment: I just want to know is it possible somehow to configure the svn access to the HTTP/svn ( the root directory of all repos ). with at least one user so i can see all of repos.

Comment: The problem is that the repository name is not included in the authorization access. If you specify `/`, you're specifying the root of all the repositories. If you need separate access for each, you'll have to have each repository with its own auth file. Then, a single user can be in all three auth files. My personal preference is to use LDAP (especially if you use Windows Active Directory). Then you can setup each to use Windows groups and forget the auth file.

Comment: I'm happy with current situation, thant i have one file with user names and second file with permissions. i can specify there which user can access which project. And i undestood whay you mean about the / beeing root for all repositories... thanx.

Answer (score 1):

If you using Apache (Mod_Dav_Svn) to expose your repository then you need to add Auth support to the  Directive in your apache conf file

```
<location ...>
   ... 
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "My Subversion repository"
   AuthUserFile /srv/svn/conf/passwd
</Location>
```

In the file referenced in the AuthUserFile you can specify the permissions you need like so:

```
[/]
* =
[project1:/]
internal_developer = rw
external_developer_1 = 
external_developer_2 =
[project2:/]
internal_developer = rw
external_developer_1 =  rw
external_developer_2 =
[project2:/]
internal_developer = rw
external_developer_1 = 
external_developer_2 = rw
```

You can also set permissions at a more granular level on a per folder basis as follows

```
[/project1:/public_folder]
* = r
```

I hope this helps?

You might also want to consider using a third party to host your code, [CodeSpaces.com](http://www.codespaces.com) do subversion hosting that have granular permissions, plus you don't have the headache of managing your own infrastructure, backups, etc...